# Upload from CSV file to DHTMLX GANTT

Tags: csv, file-upload, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

There is a custom implementation in dhtmlx gantt for upload from MPP/XML which goes to their servlet and renders the gantt. Has anyone tried to build a custom CSV upload or any third parties available to load the csv into the gantt.
https://dhtmlx.com/blog/export-import-ms-project-dhtmlx-gantt-chart/

Answer (score 0):

There is no such solution from DHTMLX (FYI I work for DHTMLX), and I'm not aware if there is any third-party service or ready-to-use solution that could be used for a development.

At the code level, importing csv into gantt breaks down into three steps:

1. parsing CSV into an object array
2. mapping columns of CSV to properties of that objects (mandatory properties of gantt tasks - [text/start_date/duration/parent](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__supported_data_formats.html#json))
3. and inserting the result into database.

The first step is trivial. Mapping columns may require implementing some sort of UI so the user could specify which columns of csv mean what in gantt. 
For an inspiration, you can check how it's done in this app https://app.ganttpro.com/ - requires registration, but you can create a free account using google or facebook acc - create new project ("+ CREATE NEW" in lefthand menu), select "Import from" and try uploading some csv file -> [here is how the ui looks like](https://www.screencast.com/t/lWMNtOxr).

As for the last step - inserting parsed records into db - you'll need to do some coding in order to insert tasks without losing project hierarchy (task.parent -> task.id relations, given that database ids of your items will likely change after inserting), but overall it shouldn't be very difficult.

If you looking for something more specific - please update your question.